# The name and origin of the doctrine of justification by restructuring the narrative

Tags: forgiveness, justification, systematic-theology

See the example of the candlesticks [from Les Mis](https://youtu.be/yhpwV4cwB4o?t=1m46s).

See also Gen 20:60

> ...you meant it for evil, but God meant it for good.

Can someone tell me the name and origin of this theological concept?

Specifically, what is the name and origin of the idea that God justifies a sinful act by restructuring the narrative surrounding it?

Comment: Note this is not off topic.  It is question type 3.  see post https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines

Comment: Why are you using the term"justification" in your question? Perhaps redemption would be more appropriate?

Comment: @bruisedreed you're right that redeem could also be used here. Also vindicated. The concept is that something is changed from bad to good, without changing the thing itself, but instead by changing the world around it.